# RealmResult as RealmObject field

Tags: android, realm

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up a RealmObject with a RealmResult as one of its fields.

For example, let's say I have two RealmObjects, `Goal` and `Achievement`.  The Goal object contains fields that define a query of Achievement's the user wants to track (e.g. date range the achievement was created, type of achievement, etc) and has custom methods to extract statistics from those Achievements.

What is the best way for Goal to contain this RealmResult of Achievements?  Here are some ways I've thought of doing this:

1. Have a persisted RealmList field in Goal and update it anytime a field is changed that would change the resulting query.  But how would this RealmList get updated if a new Achievement gets added to the realm?
2. Use `@Ignore` annotation on a `RealmResult<Achievement>` field within Goal.  Anywhere in Goal where mResult is used, first check if null and requery if needed.  This seems like I will be doing a lot of unneccessary querying if I'm using something like a RecyclerView that refetches the object in `getItem()`.
3. Have a wrapper class that contains a Goal object and the `RealmResult<Achievement>` as fields.  Add a listener to Goal so that anytime a relevant field changes the RealmResult can be requeried.

I'm leaning towards the last one as the cleanest way to keep a valid RealmResult.  Am I missing an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: reminds me of [this idea](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3210#issuecomment-234908853) but it's on "idea backlog" so it won't happen anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks, @EpicPandaForce! Do you know what the best way to accomplish this would be, assuming we don't get @Query anytime soon?

Comment: Personally I'd probably just have an abstraction akin to `RealmResults<Achievement> achievements = achievementDao.findForGoal(realm, goalId);`... but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I'm trying to implement a wrapper class (which I think is similar to the DAO abstraction @EpicPandaForce was mentioning, but I'm not super familiar with that)

```
public class GoalWrapper {
    private RealmResults<Achievements> mResults;
    private Goal mGoal;
    private Realm mRealm;

    public GoalWrapper(Realm realm, Goal goal) {
        mRealm = realm;
        mGoal = goal;

        // TODO: does this need to be removed somewhere?  What happens when GoalWrapper gets GC'd?
        goal.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmModel element) {
                // rerun the query
                findResultForGoal();
            }
        });

        findResultForGoal();
    }

    /**
     * Run a query for the given goal and calculate the result
     */
    private void findResultForGoal() {
        mResults = mRealm.where(Achievement.class)
                .greaterThanOrEqualTo("date", mGoal.getStartDate())
                .lessThanOrEqualTo("date", mGoal.getEndDate())
                .equalTo("type", mGoal.getAchievementType())
                .findAll();
        calculateStats();
    }

    private void calculateStats() {
        // Get relevant stats from mResult...
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code yet but I plan to have a RecyclerView.Adapter with an ArrayList of GoalWrapper objects.

My one concern is that I never remove the listener on mGoal.  Do I even need to remove it?  What happens in the case that the ArrayList gets GC'ed?  I would think that the Goal field and resulting listeners attached to it all get GC'ed as well.

Comment: If you create the GoalWrapper only when you call `realmResults.get(i)` which means in `onBindViewHolder()` then you'll keep lazy evaluation instead of having to keep all goals in an ArrayList.

Comment: Doesn&#39;t that come with the cost of having to rerun findResultForGoal every time, instead of once when the goals are first queried? 
calculateStats implementation isn't shown but it has to loop through every Achievement in the result too.

Comment: well *that's* true... depending on the number of elements, too many `findAll()` calls can cause slow-down. ArrayList also works, yes.